# Is it possible to delay a scroll activated transition, which uses the ::after modifier, until the element is scrolled past?

Tags: html, css, transition

good evening,

i'm working on a child theme for Septera,
https://www.cryoutcreations.eu/wordpress-themes/septera

this theme has a nice transition effect on the background of the header menu, from transparent to a set color. this is accomplished by using the **::after** modifier and the **transition** effect.

```
.header-fixed#site-header-main,
.header-fixed#site-header-main #access::after {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out 1s, color;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out 1s, color; }
```

currently, the scroll effect initiates after a page scroll of 85px, the height of the element which the transition effects.

is there any possible way to delay the activation until the scroll is past that element by an additional 100px?

i've tried adding both margin and padding to the element, and it only makes the menu bigger. does nothing to delay the start of the transition effect.

i tried adding :

```
.header-fixed#site-header-main #access::before { margin-bottom:100px; }
```

hoping to add another 100px in scroll distance before the ::after modifier was triggered... but it does nothing to delay the transition effect.

any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I guess you will need to look more at the JS than the CSS file ... Aside your link didn't work for me

Comment: i believed the transition effect to be accomplished entirely with CSS, i'm out of luck if it's JS driven :( the page i linked won't work for me either, but i assumed it was due to my location :(( thanks